# Interfaces returning Any? but concretes returning something concrete

Tags: swift, oop

> I believe I have solved this with thanks to the current 1pointer answer and generics. I'll update the answer below and add it to that. Thanks!

### Attempting to create a command bus

I'm struggling to create a command bus in Swift. The problem I'm having right now is that I'm trying to make this thing generic enough to handle different commands, but as a result in many cases I have to return an `Any`, and this means I'll have to be performing in-code checks for everything all the time, and I'm not sure what I can do about that.

### Code

```
protocol Command { }

struct TestCommand: Command
{ 
    public let value: int = 1
}

protocol CommandHandler
{
    func execute(_ command: Command) -> Any?
}

struct TestCommandHandler: CommandHandler
{
    public func execute(_ command: Command) -> Any?
    {
         // First problem - I have to cast command as! TestCommand
         // due to the interface
    }
}
```

And finally below is the command bus which basically just maps a command given to it to a handler and returns it. Nothing special or complicated.

```
struct CommandBus
{
    public let container: Container

    /// Added as closures so the commands are only resolved when requested
    private func commandMap() -> Array<[String: () -> (Any)]>
    {
        // TestCommand implements an empty protocol CommandProtocol
        return [
            [String(describing: TestCommand.self): { self.container.resolve(TestCommandHandler.self)! }]
        ]
    }

    /// Dispatch a command to the relevant command handler
    public func dispatch(_ command: Command) -> Any
    {
        let map = self.commandMap()
        let commandName = String(describing: command.self)
        let element = map.enumerated().first(where: { $0.element.keys.first == commandName })
        let elementIndex = map.index(element!.offset, offsetBy: 0)
        let commandHandler: CommandHandler = map[elementIndex].first!.value() as! CommandHandler

        return commandHandler.execute(command)!
    }
}
```

The command buses' only responsibility really is to figure out what command handler to invoke and to return the result.

### The Problem

Here are the problems with what I have right now:

- The concrete command handler is *always* going to have to do a check that the object I pass in is of a certain concrete type, and cast it with an `as` just so I can use it (in this case the handler wants to be able to get the `value` out of the command)
- The command bus is always returning an `Any` so whatever scalars I return there's going to have to be checks that they exist in the controller that creates the command and passes it to the command bus

So - can I use generics to solve any of my problems here? Is this more of an architecture or OO problem? Or is what I'm after basically not possible because this is a strictly typed language?

I think there's something obvious I'm missing here. How can I create what I need whilst retaining decent typing where I don't have to tell the compiler everything every step of the way. Is this even possible?

### What I've tried...

Someone suggested I could also use protocols with associated types but I'm not sure exactly where to put this or how to do this. I've also thought of a 'Request/Response' style thing where each command returns a response, but that would have to be a protocol, which basically takes me back to the `Any` problem.

I also tried changing the `CommandBus` signature to: `public func retrieveHandler<T: CommandHandler>(_ command: Command) -> T`. I must now pass a command to the function with a type declaration:

```
let handler: ConcreteHandlerName = commandBus.retrieveHandler(command)
```

Comment: The first thing you can do is not double space all your code ;)

Comment: You’d prefer each assignment were directly next to each other when in some cases they’re not related? That’s going to be harder to read?

Comment: What's hard to read is scrolling 2 screen lengths for 10 lines of code.

Comment: Hmm, so I can put the five lets together but there’s still a scroll there. I’ll take your feedback onboard though and so can separate out the code into blocks so there’s no scrolling. If you have anything other than coding standards input though it would be appreciated :)

Comment: I don't, or else I would have answered already :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want because I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve, but take a look at this Playground code I've put together:

```
import Foundation

protocol CommandProtocol {

    associatedtype Handler: CommandHandlerProtocol
    associatedtype Result

}

protocol CommandHandlerProtocol {

    associatedtype Command: CommandProtocol

    func execute(_ command: Command) -> Command.Result
    init()

}

class IntCommand: CommandProtocol {

    typealias Handler = IntCommandHandler
    typealias Result = Int
}

class IntCommandHandler: CommandHandlerProtocol {

    typealias Command = IntCommand

    func execute(_ command: Command) -> Command.Result {
        return 5
    }

    required init() { }
}

class StringCommand: CommandProtocol {

    typealias Handler = StringCommandHandler
    typealias Result = String
}

class StringCommandHandler: CommandHandlerProtocol {

    typealias Command = StringCommand

    func execute(_ command: Command) -> Command.Result {
        return "Hello!"
    }

    required init() { }
}

class CommandBus {

    public var map: [String: Any] = [:]

    func dispatch<T: CommandProtocol>(_ command: T) -> T.Handler.Command.Result {
        let handlerClass = map[String(describing: type(of: command))] as! T.Handler.Type
        let handler = handlerClass.init() as T.Handler
        return handler.execute(command as! T.Handler.Command)
    }

}

let commandBus = CommandBus()
commandBus.map[String(describing: IntCommand.self)] = IntCommandHandler.self
commandBus.map[String(describing: StringCommand.self)] = StringCommandHandler.self

let intResult = commandBus.dispatch(IntCommand())
print(intResult)

let stringResult = commandBus.dispatch(StringCommand())
print(stringResult)
```

[image]

### Update

Here's a `CommandBus` that maps to specific instances of a handler instead of just it's type. That means the `init` method from `CommandHandlerProtocol` can be removed.

Also I've hidden the `map` property and instead added a method to add the mapping. This way your types are always correct when creating a map:

```
protocol CommandHandlerProtocol {

    associatedtype Command: CommandProtocol

    func execute(_ command: Command) -> Command.Result

}

class CommandBus {

    private var map: [String: Any] = [:]

    func map<T: CommandProtocol>(_ commandType: T.Type, to handler: T.Handler) {
        map[String(describing: commandType)] = handler
    }

    func dispatch<T: CommandProtocol>(_ command: T) -> T.Handler.Command.Result {
        let handler = map[String(describing: type(of: command))] as! T.Handler
        return handler.execute(command as! T.Handler.Command)
    }

}

let commandBus = CommandBus()
commandBus.map(IntCommand.self, to: IntCommandHandler())
commandBus.map(StringCommand.self, to: StringCommandHandler())

let intResult = commandBus.dispatch(IntCommand())
print(intResult)

let stringResult = commandBus.dispatch(StringCommand())
print(stringResult)
```

Comment: Nice! I see you've made it so that the dev registers the commands at runtime instead of compile time. Is there any reason the protocol has an `init()` in it? Would there be any way to not provide an init - because the init will likely require different arguments depending on the handler.

Comment: Well, you can change the map to actually take an initialised handler and not a handler type. That way you can go without the init. But not sure what you mean about the compile time map... Let me add an example with handler instances instead of types that need to be init

Comment: Thanks Mihai for your effort and a great answer! This is super useful and exactly what I want :) Bounty's yours.

Answer (score 1):

`associatedtype` is the answer to your question:

```
protocol Command { }

protocol CommandHandler {
    associatedtype CommandType: Command // the concrete `CommandType` must conform to `Command`
    associatedtype ReturnType           // each handler will define what the return type is

    func execute(_ command: CommandType) -> ReturnType?
}

struct TestCommand: Command {
    public let value = 1
}

struct TestCommandHandler: CommandHandler {
    typealias CommandType = TestCommand
    typealias ReturnType = Int

    public func execute(_ command: CommandType) -> ReturnType? {
        // now `command` is of type `TestCommand` and the return value is `Int?`
        return 42
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what your `CommandBus` is supposed to do so I am skipping that part of your question.

Comment: The `CommandBus` - you pass `dispatch()` an instance of a `Command`, and it finds the correct `CommandHandler` class, instantiates it, then calls execute. How does it find this handler? The dev has to place the command => handler in `commandMap`. All those 6 lets do is search the array keys for the command and then return the value that is the handler. It's just a mapper between the command and it's handler.

Comment: The problem now is that my `CommandBus` cannot return an instance of `CommandHandler` because I get this error: > Protocol 'CommandHandler' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements